# Yet Another Peak Detection Request

Tags: frequency-spectrum, signal-analysis, statistics, peak-detection

I looked over the other entries regarding peak detection and none seem to answer my question.

I'm working with Fourier spectra of digitized audio that can't be measured again. There are no constraints on the nature of the audio.

Finding outliers is easy. I'm worried about "fat" peaks whose contours might be made jagged by background noise. Their "summits" are peaks among peaks. So how salient and separate does a peak need to be in order to qualify?

Is there a statistical way of approaching the problem? I could do something ad hoc, but without firm theoretical grounding, I rely much more on testing to confirm the algorithm's robustness. I'd like to know theoretically, rather than empirically, that my algorithm is sound.

Also, for those who have read this far, is there a good corpus of audio test data I can use for analysis algorithms?

Comment: Needed is your definition of when a peak is not a peak. For what reasons aren't you considering all peaks to be peaks?

Comment: I'm realizing that my question is poorly conceived. Should I just go ahead and delete it?

Comment: @hotpaw2 I disagree with your take. The problem *is*, how do we actually *define* a peak, or what family of definitions exist for it. (ie, what features might a pattern recognizer extract such that it determines something is a peak).

Comment: @hotpaw2 Furthermore, this is a broad (but good!) question that lends itself to multi-scale analysis ala-wavelets, for example. Again, the 'definition' of a peak need not be given per se. In the same way we dont 'define' a car, yet pattern recognition on images can pull them out via (invariant) feature extraction.

Comment: MackTuesday, do you have data you can put up, as say, a .mat file?

Comment: mack, it's not an illegit question.  i'm curious about *"Fourier spectra of digitized audio that can't be measured again"*.  but you still have access to the original audio, no?  how is the spectra computed?  is not the audio windowed before going into the FFT?  knowing the nature of that window will tell you alot about the nature of the peaks.

Comment: Yeah, even *I* wasn't clear on what I thought was a peak. I'm modeling audio as a number of modulated sinusoids (making them broad-band) along with some noisy, transient-y residual. I've been thinking that the salience of a peak depends on not only its absolute intensity, but also its intensity relative to its neighboring bins. So a smallish peak on a big hill might be modulation or noise, but a peak of the same size poking out of some some low flat area should be treated as a legitimate partial.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson That phrase was meant to clarify that this audio isn't coming from a repeatable process, so methods involving multiple measurements aren't applicable here. I do have the original audio, I just meant to say that I'm looking for peaks in the spectrum as opposed to the time domain. Right now I'm using a Hann window because I figure the biggest sideband is at -30dB, which seems to be quiet enough that overlapping skirts won't be a great problem.

Comment: By the way, I'm aware of the likes of Spectral Modeling Synthesis and Loris. I don't really like these approaches because they don't *decompose* the signal, they just tell you what's there. "Resynthesis" in these cases is actually just synthesis, where you hope your synthesis algorithm interprets the analysis data well enough to give you a good approximation of the original signal. I'm trying to use analysis to guide matching pursuit, which gives you actual components of the signal to manipulate.

Comment: @user4619 Take any complex audio. That will be as meaningful and useful as a reference as anything I could send you.

Comment: @MackTuesday I do not know what 'complex audio' is. Not everyone shares your application area. Eitherway, data - or at least an image of it - goes a long way. I have a technique in mind but it will be impossible to know if it fits your needs without seeing some data.

Comment: @user4619 I just realized that I might have sounded a bit short in my last comment. Absolutely didn't mean to, sorry. Sorry also for being ignorant: how do I put up data you can see? Shall I PM it to you? Email? Is there some sort of bulletin board where I can put it?

Comment: No harm done. You can attach it to here, or I can shoot you an email. Do you have an email you can be reached at?

Comment: Here's a Google Docs link. ( [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Am7hHMy3mkWXhGcUFYT1J2QWM/edit?usp=sharing) ) It's the magnitude spectrum of a portion of audio in ASCII. (Hope that format is viable.) In bins 400-600 or so, you can see a couple of concentrations of energy in addition to the obvious peaks. They're made of densely packed smaller peaks, any of which, standing alone, would clearly be partials. As they are, it looks like they should be taken together as a modulated sinusoid instead. So I wonder how we can do with an algorithm what can easily be done with the eye.

Comment: And let me emphasize that no one example should be taken to represent all of the signals I'm interested in. I need a generic method that doesn't require prior knowledge of the data.

Comment: @MackTuesday So something like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4724281/spectrakPeaks.png) perhaps? PS: You have to put an @ symbol before my name so that I know you have replied.

Comment: @user4619 Thanks. This is a good start, but like I said, there are also two concentrations of energy near bin 500 that I'd like to detect. In my model, "hills" are just as important as "spires". I *am* interested in how your algorithm works, however.